# Can you use the Ionic Framework to build hybrid mobile apps and desktop web apps with one code base?

Tags: angularjs, css, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm really big on the idea of using a "one size fits all" approach and controlling UI/JS through smart ways like media queries/match media. I also believe in the "mobile first" approach and how this can weigh in heavily for performance (especially for mobile). That being said, I'm a little confused on how a framework such as Ionic can be used to do this? For example the "tabs".

```
<ion-tabs></ion-tabs>
```

This is not regular html, of course.. I'm a little confused on how both could be used for the same app. Can this be considered the shadow DOM? What is the browser compatibility I wonder?

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing to do with shadow DOM. That's called a Directive. It's an Angular thing.

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

The framework itself was specifically made for mobile apps, however there is TECHNICALLY nothing stopping you from using it on desktop... except for one thing: Browser Support.

Ionic targets webkit-based browsers, so you would nee to add in support for Firefox and IE manually.